# How are civicrm_group and civicrm_uf_group related?

Tags: wordpress, profile, error, 4.7

Running WordPress CiviCRM version 4.7.7

**In the log below, where is this gid coming from?** I checked all civicrm_uf_* tables and there is no reference gid=14. Is there another relationship with another table I am missing?

The only reference to **Profiles** I can find in the UI is on **Administer/Custom Data and Screens/Profile**. There is no gid=14 listed.

In the website I am administering the ids and names in **civicrm_uf_group** and **civicrm_group** look almost identical, but civicrm_uf_group is missing gid=14 and civicrm_group is not.

So where do you Administer the civicrm_group in the CiviCRM user interface?

Even knowing which page or menu item is causing this error would be helpful.

***See the following CiviCRM log:***

> May 29 15:06:44 [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array ( [message] => The requested Profile (gid=14) is disabled OR it is not > > configured to be used for 'Profile' listings in its Settings OR there is no Profile with that ID OR you do not have permission to access this profile. Please contact the site administrator if you need assistance. [code] => )
>
> May 29 15:06:44 [info] $backTrace = #0 /../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(371): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
>
> > 1. /../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/UFGroup.php(368): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("The requested Profile (gid=14) is disabled OR it is not configured to be used...")
> > 2. /../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/UFGroup.php(217): CRM_Core_BAO_UFGroup::getFields("14", FALSE, 2, 5, FALSE, FALSE, "Profile", 5, NULL, 5)
> > 3. /../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Profile/Page/Listings.php(143): CRM_Core_BAO_UFGroup::getListingFields(2, 5, FALSE, "14", FALSE, "Profile", 5)
> > 4. /../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Profile/Page/Listings.php(288): CRM_Profile_Page_Listings->preProcess()
> > 5. /../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Profile/Page/Router.php(124): CRM_Profile_Page_Listings->run()
> > 6. /../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Profile_Page_Router->run((Array:2), NULL)
> > 7. /../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
> > 8. /../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:2))
> > 9. /../wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1227): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:2)) 10.internal function: CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke(Object(WP))
> > 10. /../wp-includes/plugin.php(601): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:1))
> > 11. /../wp-includes/class-wp.php(737): do_action_ref_array("wp", (Array:1))
> > 12. /../wp-includes/functions.php(952): WP->main("")
> > 13. /../wp-blog-header.php(16): wp()
> > 14. /../index.php(17): require("/var/www/vhosts/casem-acmse.org/httpdocs/wp-blog-header.php")
> > 15. {main}

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that civicrm_group has nothing to do with civicrm_uf_group.  The former is actual groups, while the latter is profiles (groups of user-frontend fields).

If you have no profile with that ID, that would explain why you don't have access. The question really comes down to why you'd have a link there.